# Trying to make a binary search on an ordered array in Motorola 68k assembly

Tags: assembly, motorola, 68000, easy68k

I am trying to find out how to make a binary search subroutine on an ORDERED array, using m68k. For Java, I would do

```
int binSearch(int key, int &lo, int &hi) 
{
    if (hi < lo)
        return NOT_FOUND;                  //RETURN with V = 1  
    int mid = (lo+hi) / 2;
    if (key == array[mid])
        return mid;
    else if (key < array[mid])             // go left
        return binSearch(key, lo, mid-1);  // left
    else
       return binSearch(key, mid+1, hi);   // right
}
```

Im trying to put that to assembly. What I have so far is

```
link        A6,#0
movem.l     D1/A1-A2,-(sp) 
move.w      8(A6),D1   *key t
movea.l     10(A6),A1  *lo
movea.l     14(A6),A2  *hi
cmpa.l      A1,A2 *if hi>lo
BHS            else
move.l      A1,D1 *low D1
add.l       A2,D1 *adds hi
asr.l       #1,D1 * divide by 2
```

Basically, what do I do at this point? Do I compare D1 to the number im searching for, and then depending on if it is lower and higher, call the subroutine again? Does D1 hold the number at the midway point like I want it to do, or am I wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint: You can trivially do away with recursion here in favor of a simple loop.

Comment: 500 - Internal Server Error i'm really trying to do it recursively in order to learn how recursion works in assembly. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't actually know M68 assembly. If I were given this task, though, I would look at what my favorite compiler emitted for what you have up top.

Answer (score 1):

Loop method:

```
           ORG $1000
START
            LEA       ARRAY,A0     ; start of array
            MOVE.L    #KEY,D0      ; key to find
            MOVE.W    #ELEMENTS,D1 ; length of array
            BSR.S     BINSEARCH
            ; D0 contains mid or -1 if fail
            SIMHALT

BINSEARCH
            MOVE.W     D1,D2       ; high
            MOVEQ      #0,D1       ; low
BINLOOP
            CMP.W      D2,D1       ; hi = low?
            BMI.S      NOT_FOUND
            MOVE.W     D2,D3       
            ADD.W      D1,D3
            LSR.W      #1,D3          ;mid

; there are no scaled index methods on a basic 68k
; check also that word index register addressing works on CPU
; if not some operations will have to be changed to long word

            MOVE.W     D3,D4
            LSL.W      #2,D4          ; *4 for long word
            CMP.L      (A0, D4.W),D0  ; compare mid element to key
            BEQ.S      BIN_FOUND
            BMI.S      SETLO
 SETHI      SUBQ.W     #1,D2
            MOVE.W     D3,D2          ; hi = mid-1

            BRA.S      BINLOOP
 SETLO      ADDQ.W     #1,D3
            MOVE.W     D3,D1          ; lo = mid+1
            BRA.S      BINLOOP
 NOT_FOUND  MOVEQ      #-1,D3           
 BIN_FOUND  MOVE.W     D3,D0          ; return index or -1
            RTS

            ORG $1400
ARRAY       DC.L        1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
ARRAYEND
ELEMENTS    EQU         (ARRAYEND-ARRAY)/4
KEY         EQU          3
```

Comment: Does m68k not have scaled-index addressing modes you can use instead of copying D3 and using `lsl.w #2, D4`?  Or are they slow?  http://www.osdata.com/topic/language/asm/address.htm suggests that m68k has scaled index.  Without a scaled-index, you could maybe use byte offsets instead of indices, but then you'd need to AND after `lsr` to round to the nearest 4-byte offset, I think.  Or use pointers instead of indices and sub at the end, with a different midpoint calc to avoid overflow.

Comment: On modern CPUs, it's normally good to use branchless conditional-mov or similar to update hi/lo.  I guess m68k typically had lower branch-miss penalties and higher cost per instruction, so this might be ok.

Comment: Basic 68000 does not have scaled indexing. Later versions do.
Knock yourself out writing an alternative version if you wish :)